# How to get the original combination of numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy arrays and I am able to get all the combination by adding these two arrays where none of the rows have any zeros left but while doing so I loose the original constituent of the array and I am not sure how the retrieve that piece of information. Please look below at my code:

```py
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

y= np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
combos = (x + y).reshape(-1, 12).astype("int")
mask = np.any(np.equal(combos, 0), axis=1)
combos=combos[~mask]
print("combos:",combos)

# Prints
combos: [[1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1]]
```

Now from the above result I need to know what are the row values of x and y that created combos, for example for the first row:

Combos[0] = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]

X         = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

Y         = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Answer (score 0):

While you could try and reconstruct the combinations from the sums, taking note of the combinations while summing them up is definitely better. Instead of

```
x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
combos = (x + y).reshape(-1, 12).astype("int")
mask = np.any(np.equal(combos, 0), axis=1)
combos=combos[~mask]
print("combos:",combos)
```

you could try something like this:

```
combos=dict()
for e in x:
    for f in y:
        combo=e+f
        tp=tuple(combo)
        if 0 in tp:
            continue
        if tp not in combos:
            combos[tp]=set()
        combos[tp].add((tuple(e),tuple(f)))
for e in combos:
    print(e)
    for f in combos[e]:
        print("->{}{}".format(f[0],f[1]))
```

(The resulting dictionary has sums as keys and sets of combinations as values, all in tuple form. Of course, you can also store indices of x and y used to save on space instead and I strongly recommend doing so.)

Comment: The whole idea of using the original code was to replace for loops. Performance is big criteria and the original code is very performance oriented. I have to use this combination multiple times with different ranges and 4 for loops would make it nonviable for larger values.

Comment: @deejay217 The last 2 loops are just for printing the results and the code's time complexity is just as good as yours - your for loops are just hidden. And if you don't believe me, you can run my code on the higher values you mentioned and see for yourself. (Also, I edited in the "no zeros in sum" condition I missed while reading at first.)

Comment: @deejay217 Also, having 4 loops nested in each other (O(n^4)) is not the same as having a loop nested in another loop twice(O(2*n^2)).

Answer (score 0):

It may help if the `(x+y)` isn't flattened.  The mask then shows True for which x and y indices generate non zero rows.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
y= np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
temp = x + y
```

Generate the mask of which x, y indices are entirely non zero.

```
mask = ~np.any(temp == 0, axis=2)
mask
Out[8]:
array([[False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]])

x_ix = np.indices((x.shape[0], y.shape[0]))[0, mask]
x_ix
Out[12]: array([0, 4, 5, 8])

y_ix = np.indices((x.shape[0], y.shape[0]))[1, mask]
y_ix
Out[13]: array([3, 0, 3, 0])
```

The x_ix and y_ix arrays identify the index combinations which produce the required results.

This may not give exactly what you need but may point to a solution.